# Routing in symfony not working giving .html data after creating api for mobile

Tags: php, symfony

I have given the path in routing.yml like

```
api_user_login1:
  path: /api/user/login1/{token}/{purchase}/
  defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:User:api_login1}
  methods: POST
```

and created a controller UserController under UserBundle and function named is api_login1Action

```
public function api_login1Action(Request $request,$token)//returning html data
{
    return new Response($jsonContent);
}
```

Please correct it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specified which version of Symfony do you use and what do you want to get instead html. I will assume, that you need JSON response (by `$jsonContent` variable).

In order to get JSON response in Symfony, you should return JSON response object, like this:

```
public function api_login1Action(Request $request,$token)//returning html data
{
    $this->json($jsonContent);
}
```

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#returning-json-response) is documentation.